# Chrw() Anomally: Invisible Values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I found an anomaly that I don't understand. I generated a list of special characters (into a column of cells) using the Chrw() function and the list was created just fine.  However some of the cells appeared to be empty with no text, numbers, characters or spaces.  I wanted to remove rows that had blank spaces so I ran some code to delete EntireRows that contained nothing in that particular column.  But no rows were deleted.  The blank cells remained and it wasn't because of any problem with my delete code.  Even though the cells were blank, even checking the cell content bar for no spaces or characters, they would not delete unless I first physically clicked on the cell and hit the "delete" key.  So I discovered that there must have been some invisible value produced by the Chrw() function that did not physically show in the cell or the cell content bar.  An example of this anomaly would be Chrw(877)

Alternatively, some of the cells that appeared blank would not show a character in the cell until you clicked on the cell content bar.  Then a character would appear in the cell.  An example of this would be Chrw(860) theough Chrw(866).  Additionally even though the character showed in the content bar you could not copy it or even move the cursor with the arrow key in the bar.

Finally, I tested a couple of different of these invisible values to see if they match.  And they don't.  At least they did not match on the two I compared.  I didn't compare the rest of them.

What is happening?  Can we use these invisible values in code?

Here is the code that produced the list in column H:

```
Sub Create_Special_Character_List()

    Dim rowCounter As Long

    rowCounter = 1

        For i = 0 To 65535
            Sheet1.Range("H" & rowCounter) = ChrW(i)
            Sheet1.Range("I" & rowCounter) = i
            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
        Next i

    End Sub
```

Here is my delete code:

```
Sub getRidOfBlanks()

    For i = 65536 To 1 Step -1
        If IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("H" & i)) Or Sheet1.Range("H" & i) = "" Or Sheet1.Range("H" & i) = " " Or Sheet1.Range("H" & i) = "  " Or Sheet1.Range("H" & i) = "   " Then
           Sheet1.Rows(i & ":" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Below is the comparison sub:

```
Sub Compare_Values_Of_2_Different_Cells()

    If Sheet1.Range("H853") = Sheet1.Range("H854") Then
    '   Actually Chrw(855) and Chrw(856)
        Debug.Print "Values Match"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Values Don't Match"
    End If

    Debug.Print "1.  " & Sheet1.Range("H853") '  Chrw(855)
    Debug.Print "2.  " & Sheet1.Range("H853") '  Chrw(856)

End Sub

'  Debug.Print Results:
'
'  Values Don't Match
'  1. ?
'  2. ?
```

Comment: Those are *Combining Diacritical Marks*. You can google that phrase to understand them better.  And the values won't match since they are not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you cannot "see" them does not mean that those characters do not exist or be used as actual data in a cell.

They are unicode characters. Specifically they are, as Ramhound mentioned, [Combining Diacritical Marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks). They are *intended* to be used with other "normal" characters and not on their own, but that does not mean that they *cannot* appear in text on their own. How they are then rendered is down to the application, in this case lacking a character to modify they are simply not rendered.

855 is [Combining Right Half Ring Above](https://www.codetable.net/decimal/855)
856 is [Combining Do Above Right](https://www.codetable.net/decimal/856)

So your cells do not contain "blanks" at all, they contain characters that simply do not get rendered or do not appear in your current font.

They are also not matched as the same because they are not. They are quite definitely different characters.